# How to set timeout for dataWithContentsOfURL:url

Tags: objective-c, ios

I would like to download with a shorter timeout, so that it is faster, and to prevent the app from crashing on a bad connection.

```
- (void) CreateTitleView {
    NSURL* url;
    NSData* imageData;
    imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url ];
    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
}
```

I am not good in objective C, so I ask for your help, to do this. Thanks.

Comment: The short timeout won't make your connection faster! But have a look at NSURLConnection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot control the download speed by setting a timeout. That would only control how long your application waited before giving up on the download. You should refactor your application to load the image data in the background, so that the UI remains responsive till the download is complete.

Check out [NSURLConnection](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsurlconnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (sendAsynchronousRequest), or [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking).

Comment: Ok. I did know the shorter timeout won't cause download faster. How about downloading from unreachable URL, setting a timeout can at least avoid unnecessary download. Then how can you set timeout on `[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]`?

Comment: @Yeung - you cannot afaik. In cases where you need to be able to control the timeout setting for retrieving data from a URL, use methods from the [`NSURLConnection`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class instead.

Answer (score 13):

These days, it's possible. The API is like that:

```
NSURLResponse* urlResponse;
NSError* error;
NSMutableURLRequest* urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:20];
NSData* d = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&error];
```